# ellipsize not working in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I need cut TextView 'name', like a "Nameeeeee...". I use ellipsize but it doesn't work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7DLS.png)

I think, i need attach right side of TextView 'name', but i dont known to whom.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/photo"
                        app:civ_circle_background_color="#CCC"

                        android:layout_width="63dp"
                        android:layout_height="74dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/photo"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/daysToBirthday"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:text="daysToBirthday"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/birthday"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/birthday" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/birthday"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="birthday"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/age"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="age"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/birthday"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ageName"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ageName"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/birthday" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ageName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:text="AgeName"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TextView` ellipsize is not working because you didn't mention it's end constraint.

These are changes required:

1. As you can see it should end to the start of `TextView` which id is ageName.
2. Width must be `0dp` which is `match_constraint` for `TextView`

Replace your `TextView` with this one below`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ageName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/photo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this suits your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/photo"
                        app:civ_circle_background_color="#CCC"
                        android:layout_width="63dp"
                        android:layout_height="74dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dp_20"
                        android:text="Nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/photo"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ageName"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/daysToBirthday"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:text="daysToBirthday"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/birthday"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/birthday" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/birthday"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="birthday"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/age"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="age"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/birthday"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ageName"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ageName"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/birthday" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ageName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:text="AgeName"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your name TextView i changed `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"`.
Moreover i have also added this attribute `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ageName"`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following elements to '@id/name' and also constrain it to the 'ageName':

```
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
```